# Повышение надежности и производительности работы R

Tags: sql, r

Мы планируем использовать R для расчета регрессионной модели для 12 млн. строк записей БД по истории из примерно 150 млн. строк.
Пока серьезного опыта работы с системой нет, но первые результаты показались очень интересными.
Поставили серверную версию R-studio под CentOS.
Для расчета регрессий используем LMLIST из библиотеки NLME.
В настоящее время опробовали для 300 тыс. записей (контрольная выборка) и ~10 млн. записей (обучающая выборка), процесс занимает около 30 минут и выглядит примерно так:

- загрузка данных с сервера БД Oracle
- расчет регрессионных моделей (несколько (около 4-6) модели)
- сохранение данных на сервере БД Oracle

Если количество записей будет значительно больше, процесс расчета может занимать около 20 часов (линейная зависимость). Расчет будет выполняться каждую ночь.

Соответственно вопросы:

- какие есть решения в системе R для ускорения расчетов (железо сейчас уже мощное, интересуют настройки, позволяющие максимально распараллелить расчеты)
- какие есть технические решения в системе R для обеспечения надежности и отказоустойчивости системы - т.е. если система "падает" на одном из серверов в процессе 20 часовых расчетов, то автоматические переключается на другой сервер и продолжает расчеты с момента падения (т.е. уже выполненные расчеты не теряются)

Comment: Вам нужно использовать [Oracl R Enterprise](https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/oracle_r_enterprise_1_41) Удачи

Answer (score 8):

Вопрос очень общий, поэтому ответ получается такой же.

По вопросам высокопроизводительных вычислений есть вот такой список: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html 
Обратите внимание на пакеты `biglm` и `speedglm`. Про параллельные вычисления и вычисления на GPU там тоже есть.

Но сперва важно понять, на что тратится время в последовательности *чтение из БД* - **построение модели** - *запись в БД*. Может быть, на чтение и запись уходит много времени? Попробуйте один раз выгрузить данные в текстовый файл и читать/писать с помощью fread/fwrite из пакета `data.table`. Причем из линейной модели сохранять только то, что нужно (базовая функция `lm` сохраняет в модельном объекте и исходные данные, и остатки).

Если нужно строить несколько моделей, то это можно просто делать на разных машинах или в нескольких копиях R, запущенных на одном многоядерном сервере.

Вопрос отказоустойчивости, мне кажется, нужно решать за пределами R. То есть развернуть систему типа Hadoop или Spark, а R при необходимости использовать как интерфейс к ним. Хотя для озвученных объемов это все стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

P.s. Если повторные расчеты делаются на старых данных + порция новых, то можно использовать способ из https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/updating-linear-regression-efficiently-when-adding-observations-and-or-predictor

Answer (score 0):

Для Вашего случая думаю подойдет "dbplyr" + Spark.