# Медленно работает функция DBWriteTable из библиотеки RJDBC

Tags: oracle, r

Данный вопрос является логическим продолжением вот этого:
[Повышение надежности и производительности работы R](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584415/)
Соединяем R studio c Oracle c использованием  библиотеки RJDBC.
Далее получаем из БД Oracle 12 млн.строк для которых требуется построение прогноза и примерно 150 млн. строк. истории.
Строим несколько регрессионных моделей и получаем необходимые результаты прогноза.
Следующая задача - полученные значения прогноза записать в соответствующую таблицу Oracle.
В настоящее время используем функцию DBWriteTable, т.е. на период сессии в Oracle создаем временную таблицу с результатами прогнозирования, далее по этой таблице апдейтим целевую таблицу с прогнозами, а по завершении сессии временная таблица удаляется.
Однако временная таблица из ~ 300 тыс. строк создается крайне медленно - около 20 минут. 
Создание этой таблицы занимает больше времени, чем все другие операции вместе взятые (загрузка данных из бд, расчет регрессий, выбор лучшей модели).
При этом в целевом решении таблица может вырасти до примерно 10 млн. строк.
Соответственно вопрос: есть ли возможность повысить скорость создания таблицы? Например, сгенерировать запрос на создание таблицы через конкатенацию отдельных строк и отправить его через DBSendUpdate (но такой запрос будет состоять из 300 тыс. - 10 млн. строк).
Возможно есть способы соединения между собой датафрейма в R и таблицы в Oracle через синтаксис DBSendUpdate?

SessionInfo:
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно как минимум посмотреть в сторону ROrcale , он работает быстрее чем RJDBC ( https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/r_to_oracle_database_connectivity). Так же никто не запрещает сделать `dbSendQuery`+ update sql в цикле( или параллельно) -- не уверен что будет выигрыш в производительности

Answer (score 3):

Создание таблицы через команду dbWriteTable из библиотеки ROracle производится примерно на 2 порядка быстрее в сравнении с библиотекой RJDBC.
Для сравнения: после установки библиотеки ROracle таблица из 1.5 млн строк создалась примерно за 1 минуту, ранее через библиотеку RJDBC таблица из 300 тыс. строк создалась более получаса.